# CSS Footer not working in Chrome Print Preview Page

Tags: css, google-chrome, model-view-controller, footer, print-preview

My CSS code for footer has been working perfectly in my MVC Webpage for last 2 years but recently it started working weird in Google Chrome. When I tried the same code in W3Schools Try It Editor, it still works fine. The footer needs to be in the bottom-center of the page and below is the code embedded in div style :

position: fixed;text-align: center;bottom: 0px;width: 100%;">

But unfortunately, now it places the content at just below half of the page. It looks Strange. I tried many stack overflow answers and it didnt work. Also tried position: absolute and position: relative and still it doesn't place the footer data at the bottom. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: this is currently [a bug in chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1486499)

Comment: Oh No!! Thanks for letting me know.